# Beginner's help with topology? (Extruding and beveling letters)

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, topology

I know I'm terrible at topology, but that's because I don't know how to properly approach it. All I read is quads = good, ngons & tris = bad. But I'm terrible at looking at a shape and being able to break it down into something I can make. For example, I'm toying around with letters, and trying to figure out how to make them better.

Can anyone advise me on how to approach these letters? (Or just letters/shapes with holes in them, etc). I know it's not that efficient, but as I said, I don't know how to do this. Any help is appreciated (or any good materials to learn this).

Also, the 'T' is stylized like that, just fyi.

[image]

Comment: you don't always need quads, it really depends on your final goal, what do you want to do with your letters?

Comment: I'd eventually like to extrude them, bevel them, and then wrap them around a cylindrical object, and have that object rotate. Honestly, I'm just having a hard time getting the letters to bevel nicely, and I think it's because of my topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 ways:

Converting your letters to mesh and working the topology so that it works fine when you bevel, but in your case it's more a matter of how your topology is than a problem of tris and ngons. Here I've made a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* and tried a bevel, then create new edges where I saw that the bevel failed:

[image]

[image]

Or keeping your letter vectorial and giving it extusion and bevel in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry*, then converting it to mesh (then, same thing, you can simplify the topology with a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! So for method 1, when you look at the letter B for example, do you tell yourself that you need to rework the topology so that you have an edge that flows all the way around the B? Or do you split the B in half (so like two capital D's on top of each other) and try to get the edge flow to fit the D shape? I'm just having such a hard time wrapping my head around where I need to place verts & edges.. -__-

Comment: I just made a X > Limited Dissolve, then tested the bevel and looked at where it failed, then created some edge loops with J (to join) or K (knife, K to activate, Z to cut through, C to cut orthogonally) in order to avoid the overlappings